# json error, Unexpected '<'

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using javascript to receive data from an arduino, to save the data on the database i'm using dapper and to test it i'm using postman.

Here's my javascript code for receiving the Json data. I'm compairing the names on my javascript code (which are use to receive the data) with the ones i'm using on my c# code that are mapped with my database, if the names match then save the data i just received in my database and post it on my website

```
 var Latitude = ("#Latitude").val();
    var Longitude = ("#Longitude").val();
    var Country = ("#Country").val();
    var ObtainedDate = ("#ObtainedDate").val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:59319/Home/Map',
    data: { Latitude: Latitude, Longitude: Longitude, Country: Country, ObtainedDate: ObtainedDate },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (lctn) {
        $.each(lctn, function (i, lctns) {
            $lctn.append(lctns.Latitude + lctns.Longitude + lctns.Country + lctns.ObtainedDate)
        });

    }
});
```

Here's the code i used to connect to my data base

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();


    public GeoDapperConnection()
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:espejo.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DbEspejo;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=IntecEspejo;Password=P@ssw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";

        var data = conn.Query<Geography>("SELECT * FROM GEOGRAPHY").ToList();
    }
```

This is to show the data from my data base

```
public List<Geography> Locations()
    {
        conn.Open();

        var data = conn.Query<Geography>("GET_LOCATION", null, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

        conn.Close();

        return data;
    }
```

And this code is to receive the data from the javascript part and send it to my database

```
public void ReceiveData(Geography Geo)
        {
            conn.Open();
            var queryParameters = new DynamicParameters();
            queryParameters.Add("@Lat", Geo.Latitude);
            queryParameters.Add("@Long", Geo.Longitude);
            queryParameters.Add("@Country", Geo.Country);
            queryParameters.Add("@DateCreated", Geo.ObtainedDate);


            var data = conn.Query("INSERT_LOCATION", queryParameters, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);


            conn.Close();

        }
```

Here's the json data i'm posting to my website
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiYOz.png)

Here's the picture of my website, it doesn't show me on my list my new data

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Ae9.png)

And this is my Geography class

```
public class Geography
    {
        [Key]
        public int RouteID { get; set; }

        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        public string ISO { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string ISO3 { get; set; }

        public DateTime ObtainedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: error is in json, right

Comment: Why don't you show us the faulty json?

Comment: @PepitoSh done, just finished editing the question

Comment: Enter the following in your browser: `http://localhost:59319/Home/Map` and publish what you get. You may be getting an error message which is being misinterpreted.

Comment: How does the `Map` method looks like ? How are you returning the Json from that ?. You should use the `Json` method instead of creating json string manually (if you are doing that)

Comment: Can you post the structure of `Geography`. Seeing error, it seems that JSON is not getting deserialized to expected model.

Comment: @user1672994 done

Comment: @Shyju i'm not using a map method

Comment: Your client side code is making a call to the `map` method ? Or the url which has that. Which method handles that request ?

Comment: @Shyju my client side code, i'm using google maps API, should i post that javascript code too?

Comment: Seeing postmap snapshot, it seems that you are sending the array of object, but the `ReceiveData` (as per your comment, it receives data from the javascript) expects an object only. It the intention to send array of object, then convert the parameter to expect `List` .

Comment: Do you have an Method for Map? A controller? I think you are sending the JSON directly to an HTML Page. This is the reason you are geting Unexpected '<'. As the first character in HTML is <.